# How to use a UNIQUE formula with an IFS formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

For example if a Uniqueifs existed, I'd have `=uniqueifs('Data'!H2:H10000, 'Data'!F2:F10000, A18)`

1. If a cell in the range of 'Data'!F2:F10000' contains the contents of the cell A18, then..
2. Print out the unique results of cells in the range of 'Data'!H2:H10000 in the corresponding row.

Sorta how a sumif formula works for numbers, but don't add them if this explains.

I'd consider my self fairly new to Google Sheets so don't make fun of me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly a simple if function should work. Try this: =arrayformula(IF(A18=F2:F,H2:H,""))